# Oracle: Query returns \u0001 in application, works fine in SQL Developer

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, character-encoding

I have following column in an SELECT query:

```
SELECT INITCAP(RTRIM(REGEXP_replace(name, '(^.+) [0-9\.]{1,}%.*', '\1'))) AS name,
```

This removes any percentage and what comes afterwards in the name field. For example:

`'MY_NAME 10% Test'` will give `'My_name'`

Some rows have this % entry, some do not. For those without it, it will just return the original value with initcaps: MY_Name -> My_name.

This works perfectly fine when running the query in SQL Developer. However when I run it in the actual application (php5, oci), all values that have a % sign are returned as unicode code point `\u0001`.

Encoding is `AL32UTF8`, both of database and connection.

What is causing this issue? How can I resolve it?

EDIT:

The issue is certainly from the regexp_replace function as just

```
REGEXP_replace(name, '(^.+) [0-9\.]{1,}%.*', '\1'))) AS name
```

causes the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the application the SQL is in a string and hence all backslashes `\` in the regex must be escaped, eg. double bachslash `\\`. eg:

```
SELECT INITCAP(RTRIM(REGEXP_replace(name, '(^.+) [0-9\\.]{1,}%.*', '\\1'))) AS name,
```